# changing plot dimensions in ggplot2 with one categorical variable

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, coordinates

I am trying to plot data with a categorical x-axis variable and a continuous y-axis variable. The current plot is shown below:

[image: categorical/continuous lineplot]

A am trying to alter the height of the y-axis to make the plot taller and thinner. I know you can do this kind of thing with a continuous variable vs. continuous variable scatterplot using coord_fixed(), e.g.:

[image: coord_fixed example]

However, this works on the numeric ratios of the x and y data, which doesn't apply if one variable is categorical. Trying coord_fixed on my data with any input seems to just scale the plot exactly to the plot area:

[image: scaled inappropriately]

Trying to adjust the canvas at the ggsave phase just adds white space around the plot, rather than changing the plot shape itself, which isn't what I'm looking for either:

ggsave(filename = paste(imgSaveDir,'RT_data_summ.png',sep=""),width=7,height=10)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. `ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +  geom_point() +   coord_fixed(.2)` changes the aspect ratio as expected.